# Apply CSS features only to one div using classes?

Tags: html, css, class

I found this tutorial on css:

http://designshack.net/articles/css/5-simple-and-practical-css-list-styles-you-can-copy-and-paste/

it says css file:

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

div {
  margin: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 500px;
}

h3 {
  font: bold 20px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

li img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}

li p {
  font: 200 12px/1.5 Georgia, Times New Roman, serif;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

li:hover {
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

and the html file:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>title</title>
 <link href="s.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixum.com/100/100/nature/1">
      <h3>Headline</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixum.com/100/100/nature/2">
      <h3>Headline</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixum.com/100/100/nature/3">
      <h3>Headline</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixum.com/100/100/nature/4">
      <h3>Headline</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

it worked great but I want to put the css features only to one div, not the whole site, so I tried to put all css features in class like this:

```
div.list{
 * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

    div {
      margin: 20px;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

and change the html to:

```
<div class="list">
```

I also tried to put them in `.list` class but I have lost all the formatting what should I do?

Comment: .. Is there a reason you can't just use IDs?

Comment: @Daedalus, what do you mean by IDs

Comment: I mean, `<span id="test">red</span>` and `#test { color: red; }`.  It's basic html.  I recommend you find a good tutorial; I recommend MDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not nest CSS classes like that. If you want to limit the application of CSS classes to elements that appear within an element with a given class name (in this case `.list`), you can prefix all the class definitions like this:

```
.list * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.list div {
  margin: 20px;
}

.list ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 500px;
}

.list h3 {
  font: bold 20px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.list li img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}

.list li p {
  font: 200 12px/1.5 Georgia, Times New Roman, serif;
}

.list li {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.list li:hover {
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

More information about CSS selectors can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).

The one used in this case is the relationship-based selector `A E` that applies style definitions to *Any E element that is a descendant of an A element (that is: a child, or a child of a child, etc.)*

Comment: thanks it worked, but this need a lot of adding, isn't there another solution

Comment: but in html file should I add class="list" to all the elements !! or can I add class="list" only to <div>.

Comment: Only the surrounding `div`. Otherwise it would indeed be too much work :-)